# How i can execute command in linux terminal without using space?

Tags: linux

How i can execute command in linux terminal without using space?

example:

`cat text.log -> cat${space_code}text.log`

Comment: Interesting question. Why would you like to do that? Would it be enough to escape the space with backslash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html) can help you to construct complex bash commands without the use of spaces:

```
$ {cat,text.log}
```

Comment: It works out of the box for me with MacOsx and Ubuntu 14.04. Just type `{cat,text.log}`

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake, +1 ( I realized it was my mistake and deleted my comment just before you wrote your comment :) )